# Как вести статистику в asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp

Какие есть возможности сбора статистики в asp.net?

Нужно собирать уникальные пользователи, кол-во запросов, количество каких-то определенных запросов и вообще поток данных

Comment: На внутреннем уровне - [Collect statistics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/collecting-application-statistics-for-aspnet-using-the-profiler-sampling-method?view=vs-2017). Внешние средства - всякие там Zabbix, Nagios: [List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_systems_management_systems), [Comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems). А ещё можно заюзать google analytics.

Comment: Как вы сайт хостить будете?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: @tym32167, Мне нужно именно на сайте, а не на хостинге